# ios remote notification payload when app is killed

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

The user has killed the app (by swiping upward). He then leaves the phone, making it fall asleep (turn off screen and so).
At this point we send a remote notification to the device - and are also getting the notification shown in the system bar.

(Here comes my question): If the user then opens the springboard normally, and clicks the app icon; how do I get the payload of the notification?

If he click the notification I will get the payload, but not if I tap the icon, but why?
Do I need to catch it in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** or in **didReceiveRemoteNotification**, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems that after a long search i stumbled over this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142523/launch-app-from-homescreen-cant-get-remote-push-payload-but-launch-from-notifi)

From 'EmilioPelaez':

You can't.

You only get the payload when launching from Notification Center because it means the user is interested on that notification.

For example, if I get a reply on Tweetbot and I want to see it, I tap on the notification, but if I only want to check my tweets, I open the app normally.

If the payload has information that the user HAS to receive, the app should contact your server and retrieve it.

Comment: grats on your first post :) Your own answer is (unfortunately) correct.

Answer (score 0):

This screen shoot is taken from the Apple Documentation.

[Here is Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

[image]

So App can't get payload on tapping on the App icon but in other ways.

Hope it help you :)